# Updateable Form in Visual Basic Access using ADODB connection and command objects

Tags: forms, vba, adodb, recordset

I've been tasked with converting over an existing adp project to a accdb project.  I'm almost finished but there's one piece of functionality I can't get to work.  I'm filling a forms RecordSet using a premade stored procedure, similar to the simple example below.

```
Dim objConn As New ADODB.connection
Dim objCmd As New ADODB.Command

'Set up connection and command object
objConn.ConnectionString = "*Connection String Here*"
objConn.Open
objCmd.ActiveConnection = objConn
objCmd.ActiveConnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
objCmd.commandText = "StoredProcName"
objCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

'Fill the recodset
Set Me.recordSet = objCmd.Execute

'Close connection
objConn.Close
```

The problem is that most of the fields within the form are bound, so that the user can change data or changing items within comboboxes.  But when trying to edit the bound controls, I can't do any sort of editting, like the form is locked.  I've also tried setting the forms recordset type property to Dynaset (Inconsistant Updates) and setting the connection object's mode property to acModeReadWrite, but to no avail.  Is there a way to achieve this using ADODB connection and command objects?

Thanks!

Comment: MS now recommends linked tables.

Comment: @Remou, it doesn't carry quite as much weight, but so do I :). Not quite as easy as adp, but close.

Comment: @DougGlancy I guess you will do as a pinch hitter :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this with bound forms and strictly ADO (as opposed to linked tables).  I've done it before with Disconnected Recordsets.  The gist of it is that you need to open a recordset client-side, set the ActiveConnection to Nothing, set the form's Recordset to the recordset you've populated the data into, then write routines to bind the data to your controls.  Then, you also have to write routines to send back data (all CRUD stuff) with a server-side recordset.  Can take a while, but it definitely can work.  There are plenty articles about disconnected recorsets out there.  I don't remember too many gotchas, it's more of the rolling out of code for nearly all of what Access will do for you automatically if the form was bound that takes time.